# How to add a multiline description post to facebook using android

Tags: android, facebook, post, multiline

Tried many different combinations below but could not get a multiline description. Haven't been able to get a definite answer on whether this can or cannot be done?

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Name" + "\n" + "After line sperator" );
        params.putString("caption", "Caption");
        params.putString("description", "this is some long <br>text that should wrap but it proably wont");
        params.putString("link", "http://www.cnn.com");
```

Comment: how do you communicate with facebook? share intents?

Comment: Found the solution already?